# Better use urn or url for namespaces in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, url, xml-namespaces, urn

Is there any difference between using url-namespaces or urn-namespaces in a wpf control library? Currently we use both:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.sample-controls.com/2016/xaml/presentation", "Sample.Controls")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("urn:simplic", "Sample.Controls")]
```

Are there some pro and contra points which prefers one of the two solutions? The main pro for using urns in my option is the noticeable name.

**EDIT:** This equestion is **not** about the difference between URN and URL! It's about the usage in WPF and `XmlnsDefinition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to use a URN or a URL for an XML schema is predominately a personal preference, i.e. there is no right or wrong.

Microsoft use URLs in WPF, both when it comes to the actual XAML and code as well as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml) so this is what I would prefer myself.